# How do you suggest multicolumn breaks after paragraphs

Tags: multicol

How do you suggest multicolumn breaks after paragraphs ?
I would like something like parameters for multicol environment and don't want manual `\columnbreak`'s.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
  This is a first paragraph 
  This is a first paragraph 
  This is a first paragraph

  \textbf{This is a second paragraph
  This is a second paragraph
  This is a second paragraph
  This is a second paragraph
  This is a second paragraph
  This is a second paragraph}

  This is a third paragraph
  This is a third paragraph
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image: result]